# fatal: unable to access '...': The requested URL returned error: 403 Using Sourcetree with gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree

Suddenly I started to receive this error on all my projects on gitlab:

git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks push -v origin master:master
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.com/username/my-editor-windows.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
Pushing to https://gitlab.com/username/my-editor-windows.git
Completed with errors, see above.

It's my only account on gitlab and it's clearly authenticated
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjxew.png)

Please give me a hint, I've no idea what to do

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I just solved it by accident)
Just in case, I'll describe what I did.
In Tools->Option->Authentication (that's the only image in my question), I deleted both saved passwords, so only my authenticated account would remain.
It worked